# Javascript Sum and Average of Array strange issue

Tags: javascript, arrays

Hey guys i have this weird issue with a javascript array that i want to calculate the sum and average of it.

So i have a prompt with an input and i'm asking the users to enter some numbers.

```js
var sums = false;
var numbersArray = [];

function calculateAverage() {
  while (sums == false) {
    var numbers = prompt("Enter Integers.", "");
    if (numbers != null) {
      console.log(numbers);
      numbersArray.push(numbers);


    } else {
      var sum = 0;
      console.log(numbersArray);
      for (var i = 0; i < numbersArray.length; i++) {
        sum += numbersArray[i];
      }

      var avg = sum / numbersArray.length;
      console.log(avg);
      sums = true;
    }
  }
}

 calculateAverage();
```

So from console logs i get the following prints

```
4
5
1
["4", "5", "1"]
150.33333333333334
```

How can this be possible?

Ok my bad! Gonna accept the first answer though cause you are all correct !

Comment: `["4", "5", "1"]` - this an array of _strings_ not numbers.

Comment: A concise way of getting the average of an array in JS is `avg = ["4", "5", "1"].reduce((p,c,_,a) => p + c/a.length,0);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert string to integer before pushing into the Array

Use parsInt

```
numbersArray.push(parseInt(numbers));
```

```js
var sums = false;
var numbersArray = [];

function calculateAverage() {
  while (sums == false) {
    var numbers = prompt("Enter Integers.", "");
    if (numbers != null) {
      console.log(numbers);
      numbersArray.push(parseInt(numbers));


    } else {
      var sum = 0;
      console.log(numbersArray);
      for (var i = 0; i < numbersArray.length; i++) {
        sum += numbersArray[i];
      }

      var avg = sum / numbersArray.length;
      console.log(avg);
      sums = true;
    }
  }
}

calculateAverage();
```

Answer (score 3):

Just do parseInt before adding

```js
var sums = false;
var numbersArray = [];

function calculateAverage() {
  while (sums == false) {
    var numbers = prompt("Enter Integers.", "");
    if (numbers != null) {
      console.log(numbers);
      numbersArray.push(numbers);


    } else {
      var sum = 0;
      console.log(numbersArray);
      for (var i = 0; i < numbersArray.length; i++) {
        sum += parseInt(numbersArray[i]);
      }

      var avg = sum / numbersArray.length;
      console.log(avg);
      sums = true;
    }
  }
}

 calculateAverage();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
sum += numbersArray[i];
```

It should be

```
sum += parseInt(numbersArray[i]);
```

Because without it you add another char to your string.

Answer (score 2):

convert the user entered variable to integer before push into array

```
numbersArray.push(+ numbers);
```

Answer (score 2):

> How can this be possible?

Right now you are dealing with array of `strings` hence the behavior.

**Convert the string into numeric values** and this should be fixed. To change string to numeric use [parseInt()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp)

```
numbersArray.push(parseInt(numbers,10));
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `parseFloat` or `parseInt` method to convert string to nuber before adding. Please find the attached code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<script>
    var sums = false;
    var numbersArray = [];

    function calculateAverage() {
        while (sums == false) {
            var numbers = prompt("Enter Integers.", "");
            if (numbers != null) {
                console.log(numbers);
                numbersArray.push(numbers);


            } else {
                var sum = 0;
                console.log(numbersArray);
                for (var i = 0; i < numbersArray.length; i++) {
                    sum += parseFloat(numbersArray[i]);
                }

                var avg = sum / numbersArray.length;
                console.log(avg);
                sums = true;
            }
        }
    }
    calculateAverage();
</script>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add parseInt to sum the integers otherwise 4,5,1 will joined to form 451 and average 451/3 = 150.33333

```js
var sums = false;
var numbersArray = [];

function calculateAverage() {
  while (sums == false) {
    var numbers = prompt("Enter Integers.", "");
    if (numbers != null) {
      console.log(numbers);
      numbersArray.push(numbers);


    } else {
      var sum = 0;
      console.log(numbersArray);
      for (var i = 0; i < numbersArray.length; i++) {
        sum += parseInt(numbersArray[i]);
      }

      var avg = sum / numbersArray.length;
      console.log(avg);
      sums = true;
    }
  }
}
window.onload = calculateAverage();
```

Answer (score 2):

Need to use `ParseInt()`

```js
var sums = false;
var numbersArray = [];
calculateAverage();

function calculateAverage() {
  while (sums == false) {
    var numbers = prompt("Enter Integers.", "");
    if (numbers != null) {
      console.log(numbers);
      numbersArray.push(numbers);


    } else {
      var sum = 0;
      console.log(numbersArray, numbersArray.length);
      for (var i = 0; i < numbersArray.length; i++) {
        sum += parseInt(numbersArray[i]);

      }
      console.log(sum);
      var avg = sum / numbersArray.length;
      console.log(avg);
      sums = true;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that you've found a solution already, but I've been using an easier package called Shortcuts. You can use `const short = require('@testgrandma/shortcuts');` to install it and then for this script you can do

```js
short.arrayave([array]);
```

It'll return you the average of the array.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@testgrandma/shortcuts

Comment: Question does not talk about npm. Mostly your answer is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: It's an NPM package that I think is easier to use to find averages and other useful functions.